# Set ReverseFqdn when creating a Public IP in an Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure, ip, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I'm using Azure's Resource Groups.  I've created a group, and now I'm trying to add a Public IP Address, and I want the ReverseFqdn, which is a child of DnsSettings, to be set.

I am trying this command:

```
New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -AllocationMethod Static -ResourceGroupName MySandboxRG1 -ReverseFqdn woodswild.com -Name MySandboxRG1PIP -Location "Central US" -DomainNameLabel mysandboxrg1dns
```

But that gives me this error message:

[image]

I've read the error message a good 20 times, and I'm not making sense of it.  If I leave off this parameter:

```
 -ReverseFqdn woodswild.com
```

Than it works.  But, I of course, the ReverseFqdn is not set. If I then try to set it after-the-fact like this:

```
$ip =get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name MySandboxRG1PIP -ResourceGroupName MySandboxRG1 
$ip.DnsSettings += @{ReverseFqdn = "woodswild.com"}
Set-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -PublicIpAddress $ip
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: If you look through my answers I've got an answer to that, I'm on mobile though so can't get to it until later

Comment: Basically the forward domain needs to point to an azure IP address in your subscription before you can register the reverse - so you need to register a dummy ip first

Comment: Thanks again Michael!  I looked over the questions you have answered and didn't spot one that would be an obvious parallel to this one.  Following up on your second comment:  So do I need to create a subscription level static IP? I'm not connecting the dots here.

Comment: It was an answer to your first question :P http://serverfault.com/questions/752744/reverse-dns-while-using-azure-resource-manager

Comment: Ahh!!!  THAT'S why I couldn't find this!!  It was on ServerFault and not StackOverflow!!  I KNEW this had been discussed.  Man, I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: If you are able, see my new comments in that post!!  Thank you!!